# Drag and drop file into QTreeWidget inside of QDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I've been searching online for days and I cant find anything to help out with my specific problem. I'm trying to set up this dialog to accept files to be dropped into the QTreeWidget, named filesTreeWidget, but everything I've been searching online doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm pretty new to QT and C++ as well, so I'm sure that doesn't help.
Thanks for any help

**Header**

```
class FileIQ : public QDialog
{
   Q_OBJECT

protected:
   void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
   void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
   void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
   void dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event);
}
```

**Cpp**

```
 FileIQ::FileIQ(QWidget *parent, DR::EnginePtr engine)
 : QDialog(parent)
 , ui(new Ui::FileIQ)
 , engine_(engine)
 {
   ui->filesTreeWidget->setAcceptDrops(true);
   ui->filesTreeWidget->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
   setAcceptDrops(true);
 }

 void FileIQ::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
 {
   foreach(const QUrl &url, event->mimeData()->urls()) {
      QString filename = url.toLocalFile();
      qDebug() << "Dropped file:" << filename;
      QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->filesTreeWidget);
      item->setText(0, filename);
  }

 }


 void FileIQ::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
 {
     event->accept();
 }

 void FileIQ::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent * event)
 {
     event->accept();
 }

 void FileIQ::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent * event)
 {
     event->accept();
 }
```

Comment: Where do you drag the elements?

Comment: I want to drag the files into a QTreeWidget named filesTreeWidget, which is located on the FileIQ Dialog
ui->filesTreeWidget

Comment: And what do you want to show in the qtreewidget? The name of the files?

Comment: Yes, that exactly

Comment: And in what part of QtreeWidget do you want it to be placed?

Comment: In the first column, I added code to add it as a top level item to the tree as well

Comment: Okay, In conclusion, you want to drag files and that the filename is placed in a topLevel child item

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: Try my solution and if it works mark it as correct please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the right thing is to implement drag and drop within `QTreeWidget`, not inside `QDialog`. To do this we must create a class that inherits from `QTreeWidget` and we must implement the following protected methods:

> [**bool QTreeWidget::dropMimeData(QTreeWidgetItem *parent, int index,
>   const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action)**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#dropMimeData)
>
> Handles the data supplied by a drag and drop operation that ended with
>   the given action in the index in the given parent item.
>
> The default implementation returns true if the drop was successfully
>   handled by decoding the mime data and inserting it into the model;
>   otherwise it returns false.
>
> [**QStringList QTreeWidget::mimeTypes() const**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#dropMimeData)
>
> Returns a list of MIME types that can be used to describe a list of
>   treewidget items.
>
> [**Qt::DropActions QTreeWidget::supportedDropActions() const**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#dropMimeData)
>
> Returns the drop actions supported by this view.

From the above we implemented this class:

```
#ifndef TREEWIDGET_H
#define TREEWIDGET_H

#include <QDropEvent>
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QFileInfo>

class FilesTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FilesTreeWidget(QWidget *parent= Q_NULLPTR):
        QTreeWidget(parent)
    {
        setAcceptDrops(true);
        setDropIndicatorShown(true);
        setColumnCount(2);
    }

protected:
    bool dropMimeData(QTreeWidgetItem *parent, int /*index*/, const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction /*action*/)
    {

        for(const QUrl url: data->urls()) {
            const QFileInfo info( url.toLocalFile());
            if(info.isFile()){
                QTreeWidgetItem *item;
                if (parent){
                    item = new QTreeWidgetItem(parent);
                    parent->setExpanded(true);
                }
                else
                    item = new QTreeWidgetItem(this);
                item->setText(0, info.fileName());
                item->setText(1, info.filePath());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    QStringList mimeTypes () const
    {
        return QStringList()<<"text/uri-list";
    }

    Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions () const
    {
        return Qt::CopyAction;
    }

};

#endif // TREEWIDGET_H
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/46551444-drag-and-drop-file-into-qtreewidget-inside-of-qdialog). If you already have a QTreeWidget assigned by Qt Designer the simplest solution is to [promote the Qt Designer QTreeWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html) to use the new class.

Output:

[image]